# changing to previous page not in history with jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am implementing an override to the back button in jquery mobile.
So that I can correctly handle going back up the tree if visits a bookmarks that targets a leaf of the tree.

The back button does nothing normally in this case because `$.mobile.urlHistory.stack` only contains the current page.
What I'm aiming to do is changePage to a page which I have programatically determined is the parent to the current page.

At the moment I'm experimenting with overriding the basic back button behaviour

```
$('a[data-rel="back"]').live('tap',handleBackButton).live('click',handleBackButton)

function handleBackButton(e) {
  var currenturl = $.mobile.activePage.data('url');
  var backurl = backUrlFromTree(currenturl);

  // handle back tree navigation ourselves
  // if we're still trying to go back but there's nowhere to go
  if($.mobile.urlHistory.activeIndex === 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();

    console.log('no history to navigate');
    console.log('going back to ' + url);

    $.mobile.changePage(url, {
      transition: "slide",
      reverse: true
    });

    $.mobile.urlHistory.clearForward();
  }
}
```

The problem here is that `changePage` calls `urlHistory.addNew` which pushes the page to the stack causing the history to be ordered incorrectly, what I actually want addNew to do is unshift the page onto the front of the stack.

Any thoughts? I was thinking I'd probably have to extend the changePage and|or addNew methods.